# EF6 - Virtual Property not saving to database after savechanges in single transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 entities set up in the follow way.

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    [Key]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Value> Values{get; set; }
}

public class Value 
{
    [Key]
    public int ValueId { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; } 
}
```

Using fluent Api, I have setup the foreign key configuration from Location to Person and also from Value to Location.

```
        // Person to Location(s)
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Locations)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Person)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        // Location to Value(s)
        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Values)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Location)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new Person, add a Location and to that location add a value.

So naturally I'll first create a person

```
[pseudo code]
var newPerson = new Person();
```

then create the Location

```
[pseudo code] 
var newLocation = new Location { Person = newPerson };
```

and then finally the value

```
[pseudo code]
var newValue = new Value { Location = newLocation };
```

DbContext.Values.Add(newValue);
DbContext.SaveChanges();

What's happening is that I'm able to successfully save the Location with the newly created person if I want but when I try to get another level down and add the value like above it's complaining about the foreign key constraint between Value and Location.

I have managed to get it to work by first adding the Location to the context and doing a save changes but this would mean that my code isn't transaction safe.

Comment: To be clear, youre trying to achieve a one to many relation between Person and Location and another one to many relation between Location and Value?

Comment: public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
public virtual Location Location { get; set; } 

you don't need the virtual extension with these declarations

Answer (score 1):

You're able to save the person because it does not include a foreign key, meaning it does not have a property for Locationid but in the case of values, it requires Locationid, that is the entire purpose of defining a relation.

When you define a relation between two tables, you simply can not avoid saving records in one of the table without the foreign key of the other table. Add the location, save the changes, in the next line, add your value and then save changes. This procedure does not make your application vulnerable in any way.

If you still don't want to do this, then instead of defining the relation with Entity Framework, make the Locationid unique in your values table and perform custom validations yourself but I wouldn't suggest that.

Comment: I've definetly done it before without having to do a saveChanges before using the entity.

Answer (score 1):

You have modeled a proper one-to-many relation ship between `Persons` and `Locations`: a `Person` has zero or more `Locations`, and every `Location` belongs to exactly one Person. If the `Person` seizes to exist, then his `Locations` also seize to exist.

However, you have modeled the relation between `Locations` and `Values` differently. Apparently if a `Location` seizes to exist, the `Values` don't have to be deleted because of the `WillCasscaseOnDelete(false)`. What would the value of `LocationId` mean if the `Location` is deleted?

You solution depends on what you intended to model:

- If you really intended a one-to-many relation, so a Location has zero or more Values and every Value belongs to exactly one Location, you should `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)`.
- If you meant that a Value belongs to zero or one Location, then model a proper one to zero-or-one relation. In that case a Value can still exist without the Location
- If you meant that a Value could belong to several Locations then model a one-to-many relation or many-to-many relation between Location and Value. In this situation you can delete a Location without its Value, because these Values might live without their Location.

Comment: This scenario I'm aiming for is definetly the first out of your solutions. I'll try change the WillCascadeOnDelete to true, but I don't think that will help my problem. Shall update. Thanks

Comment: Nope made no difference, I've voted your answer because of your contribution but I don't think it helps in answering my question.